# How do I incorporate admob ads if I don't have an XML layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

All the documentation I've read references a layout like activity_main.xml, but my app doesn't use layouts.  When I did create one per the example found [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/banner) it does display the ad, but the rest of the screen is black!

I've provided my activity good so you can see where I'm at.  All I want is to add the banner to the bottom of the screen while also having the app running and visible.  Any help would be truly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // new


        // Initialize ad system

        m_adView = new AdView(this);

       m_adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

       m_adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); //new
       layout.addView(m_adView); // new

       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice( AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR )
            .addTestDevice( "64F3835CFF94C302E82205EDC204B315" ) 
            .build() ;

       m_adView.loadAd(adRequest);}
```

The layout I created looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); //new
layout.addView(m_adView); // new
```

with the following:

```
LinearLayout layout = super.root;
layout.addView(adView);
```

Since you have no layouts you can also remove

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // new
```

I hope it works for you.